# Why get ReferenceError in an inner function?

Tags: javascript, three.js, dom-events

First of all, most of the follow code I think is not related to the question, I just think it will be more, uh.. exactly to put whole part of the code.
So just look at the line I marked first:

```
window.onload = function() {

var WebGLSupported = isWebGLSupported();
var renderer = WebGLSupported ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer() : new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, 600 );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.Camera(35,window.innerWidth/600,.1,10000);
camera.position.set( -5, 5, 25 );
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, .4 );
light.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );
scene.addLight( light );
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xbbbbbb );
scene.addLight( ambientLight );
var materialClass = WebGLSupported ? THREE.MeshLambertMaterial : THREE.MeshBasicMaterial;
var materialWall = new materialClass( { color: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'posts/wholewall.png' ) } );
var i;
var planeWalls=new Array();
for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
    planeWalls[i]=new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(18,11,1,1), materialWall);
    planeWalls[i].position.z=i*(-5);
    scene.addChild(planeWalls[i]);
}
camera.lookAt(planeWalls[1].position);


animate();
function animate() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera ); <<-------BREAK AT HERE
    requestAnimFrame( animate );
}   

}
```

When I break at that line,
and add a watch of `i` and then the debugger says:

> Exception: ReferenceError: i is not defined

then I add a watch of the array above, `planeWalls`, and also get an ReferenceError,

BUT I also add a watch of "scene",and the debugger shows its value correctly,

so I'm wondering why,

I mean, an inner function obviously can use the variable of `i`, right?

and then, I add

```
alert(i);
```

in the beginning of the inner function,

and then the debugger shows `i` correctly.

So, are there any hints for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's a debugger problem, if alert() displays it, means that it's accessible.